# Updating Automated Testcase Results in test suite using Azure Rest API

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops

I have automated test cases in my test plan with following details:

TestPlanId: 10

TestSuiteId: 11

TestCaseIds: 15, 16, 17 (All Automated)

AutomatedTestCaseFullName:

TestAzure.Services.Test.Results.Test_UpdateResults (TestCaseId: 15)

TestAzure.Services.Test.Results.Test_AddResults (TestCaseId: 16)

TestAzure.Services.Test.Results.Test_VerifyResults (TestCaseId: 17)

I am executing this test case on my local machine and later need to update test result for test case.
I'm trying to implement solution to update the result for test cases using Azure Rest API services.

Queries:

1. Do I need to create a test run in advance? If so how can I link the created Run to my Test Suite/ Test Case?
2. How can I update results for individual test cases using Azure Rest APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would issue a PATCH document to the Points endpoint: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/points/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1.

In the test suite execution you generally see one line for each case however if you have multiple configurations you see more than one line for each case.  These are the test Points.  Updating these will mark the case as passed/failed.

Patch would post to a URL such as this:
https://dev.azure.com/YOUR-ORG/YOUR-PROJECT/_apis/test/Plans/473/Suites/475/points